# Variable with constant difference in time, Fixed effect estimator

Tags: econometrics, fixed-effects-model

Suppose I want to estimate such a model:
$$ w_{i,t}= \gamma_0+x_{i,t}\gamma_1 +age_{i,t}\gamma_2 + \alpha_i+\lambda_t+\epsilon_{i,t}  $$

This is of course a model with both individual and time fixed effects. The question is whether we can estimate the $\gamma's$ consistently. Of course, you can estimate the $\gamma_1$ term consistently, and you can't estimate the $\gamma_0$ term consistently, but what about $\gamma_2$?

We have that $age_{i,t+1} =age_{i,t}+1$, i.e. the $age$ variable has a constant difference over time for every $i$.

In my attempt, I use the following "transformation" of the regression:

$$ (w_{i,t}-\overline{w_{.t}}-\overline{w_{i.}}+\overline{w}) = (x_{i,t}-\overline{x_{.t}}-\overline{x_{i.}}+\overline{x})\gamma_1 +(age_{i,t}-\overline{age_{.t}}-\overline{age_{i.}}+\overline{age})\gamma_2 +(\epsilon_{i,t}-\overline{\epsilon_{.t}}-\overline{\epsilon_{i.}}+\overline{\epsilon}) $$
This gets rid of the time and individual fixed effects for me, and so we can estimate the coefficient on $x$ quite easily. However, I cannot figure out if the $age$ term drops out due to the constant difference over time.

Answer (score 4):

The age variable will not cancel due to the within transformation. However, it will be a problem for the fixed effects estimator if you have another variable that has a constant change over time. For example, if you were to include another variable in your regression, say job market experience, which also varies at a constant rate every year, then the fixed effects estimator cannot tell the difference between the two variables anymore because their within individual variation is the same and therefore they are perfectly collinear (given that neither variable is measured with error).

Another estimator that relies on the within variation is first differences. Here it is even more intuitive to see what happens:
$$
\begin{align}
w_{it} - w_{it-1} &= \beta_1 (x_{it} - x_{it-1}) + \beta_2(age_{it} - age_{it-1}) + \beta_3(exp_{it} - exp_{it-1}) - (\epsilon_{it} - \epsilon_{it-1}) \\
\Delta w_{it} &= \beta_1 \Delta x_{it} + \beta_2 1 + \beta_3 1 + \Delta \epsilon_{it}
\end{align}
$$

So even though these variables do not drop after first differencing or applying the within transformation, their within variation is the same and so neither the within nor the first differences estimator can hold apart the relative contributions of each in the within variation of $w$.

Consider a simple simulation example in Stata:

```
/* simulate panel data with 5 time periods, 1000 individuals,
an x which is correlated with the individual fixed effect corr(x,c)=0.3,
and the true coeff on x is 0.5 */

xtarsim y x c, nid(1000) time(5) gamma(0) beta(0.5) rho(0) oneway(corr 0.3) snratio(1) seed(999)
xtset ivar tvar

// generate variable age = 31, 32, 33, 34, 35 for each individual
bysort ivar: gen age = _n + 30

// generate variable exp = 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 for each individual
bysort ivar: gen exp = _n + 10

// generate a variable which differs between individuals but varies only by 1 each year
bysort ivar: gen other = _n + ivar
```

From the summary statistics you already see that the first two variables look very similar. The third variable doesn't.

```
    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
         age |      5000           3    1.414355          1          5
         exp |      5000         103    1.414355        101        105
       other |      5000       503.5    288.7073          2       1005
```

However, when you look at the within variation of each each variable you will see that they are exactly the same, at least for the FE estimator.

```
Variable         |      Mean   Std. Dev.       Min        Max 
-----------------+--------------------------------------------
age      within  |             1.414355          1          5 
                 |                                            
exp      within  |             1.414355        101        105 
                 |                                            
other    within  |             1.414355      501.5      505.5
```

Now if the true coefficient on age is 0.7, you will get the same coefficient from the within estimator regardless which variable you use.

```
replace y = y + 0.7*age
xtreg y x age, fe
xtreg y x exp, fe
xtreg y x other, fe
```

These will all give the same coefficients for x and age/exp/other. I omitted the output to not make this post too messy but you can try it if you want to check. If you try to include both age and exp (or "other"), Stata will omit one of the variables due to perfect collinearity.

```
. xtreg y x age other, fe
note: other omitted because of collinearity

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs      =      5000
Group variable: ivar                            Number of groups   =      1000

R-sq:  within  = 0.6835                         Obs per group: min =         5
       between = 0.7046                                        avg =       5.0
       overall = 0.6685                                        max =         5

                                                F(2,3998)          =   4317.78
corr(u_i, Xb)  = 0.1581                         Prob > F           =    0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   .4943637   .0079007    62.57   0.000     .4788739    .5098534
         age |   .6929703   .0100018    69.28   0.000     .6733612    .7125794
       other |          0  (omitted)
       _cons |   .5257118   .3303602     1.59   0.112    -.1219784    1.173402
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Doing this using the first differences estimator will turn out the same conclusion.

Comment: I ran into your answer as I was wondering about a similar question. Assume age is a covariate but you also expect a linear (yearly) time trend, these will be completely collinear in a within differenced model. Thus, if you add both, one of them drops out and you won't be able to distinguish whether the coefficient on the one you retain is due to age or time effects. This rationale also holds in the time fixed effect setup of OP, does it not? Adding fixed effects for each year should also lead to identification problems or can you still add such fixed effects as covariates?