# Generalized Difference-In-Difference with join in and drop outs across span of time periods

Tags: panel-data, causality, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, plm

I have some 23 months of longitudinal data for around 22,000 users. Approximately 2,000 of those users received an intervention during that period - with the intervention occurring during any one of those 23 months. I have mocked up what this data looks like below:

The **Period** represents the usage for that month the User is active, the demographics (**Sex**, **Age**, and **BaseUsageScore**) are static throughout the dataset for a particular user, then **Trt_Group** represents group assignment and **Trt_Month** represents if that period reflects a period after treatment. **Usage** is the outcome variable.

| UserID | Period | Usage ($) | Sex | Age | BaseUsageScore | Trt_Group | Trt_Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56A783 | 2021-Jan | 50 | M | 52 | 0.5 | 1 | 0 |
| 56A783 | 2021-Feb | 80 | M | 52 | 0.5 | 1 | 0 |
| 56A783 | 2021-Mar | 100 | M | 52 | 0.5 | 1 | 0 |
| 56A783 | 2021-Apr | 75 | M | 52 | 0.5 | 1 | 1 |
| 56A783 | 2021-May | 0 | M | 52 | 0.5 | 1 | 1 |
| 30Z790 | 2021-Jan | 65 | F | 33 | 0.2 | 0 | 0 |
| 30Z790 | 2021-Feb | 30 | F | 33 | 0.2 | 0 | 0 |
| 30Z790 | 2021-March | 0 | F | 33 | 0.2 | 0 | 0 |
| 310X17 | 2022-June | 100 | M | 80 | 0.8 | 1 | 0 |
| 310X17 | 2022-July | 124 | M | 80 | 0.8 | 1 | 1 |
| 310X17 | 2022-Aug | 186 | M | 80 | 0.8 | 1 | 1 |
| 310X17 | 2022-May | 184 | M | 80 | 0.8 | 1 | 1 |

Some other things to know about the dataset:

- A user may become active and then de-activate at any point in that 23 month period (though almost all have a continuous string of periods). This coverage is similar across treatment and control.
- The control group is not demographically representative of the treatment group (younger with less males with lower BaseUsage scores), but I believe these individual differences are handled by the fixed effects model.

I am new to DiD, but with what I learned so far I've been toying with the `plm` package. Below is how I set up my model - since `Trt_Month` is always 0 for the control group I did not include the `Trt_Month*Trt_Group` interaction term:

```
plm(Usage ~ Trt_Month, index = c("UserID", "Period"), method = "within", effect = "twoways", data = df)
```

One concern is, since users' span of activity do not universally cover the observed periods that the assumption of parallel trends is violated - or would that only be the case if the span of activity differs between the groups?

Another concern (but from my understanding it should be handled by the fixed effects approach) is that a user's group assignment is to some degree influenced by `BaseUsageScore`. Should I be trying to control for this disparity outside of the model above?

Please let me know if any of this needs more clarification or detail.

Comment: In general, many analyses like these speak about the "age, period, and cohort" effects of a study, then, they simply adjust for them as variables in the model and forget about it.

Comment: If I may ask, why would a user activate or deactivate during the observation period?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Good question! A user will deactivate when they are no longer a subscriber to the platform. They may re-subscribe but that is rare (so in that case we would not have usage in those periods). Usage should not really influence activation or deactivation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One concern is, since users' span of activity do not universally cover the observed periods that the assumption of parallel trends is violated - or would that only be the case if the span of activity differs between the groups?

Neither is necessarily true.

I would imagine coverage is limited at the edges of your panel, but I can't verify this without more information. In a perfect world, you want lots of observations *around* the intervention months. In many studies, it's common to observe wider confidence intervals on the period-specific effects as we progress through time. Oftentimes this is because users may attrit as we move farther and farther away from the immediate intervention month.

I'm still curious about a few things. How many users subscribe late? What proportion have no pre-intervention usage data? Must a subscriber show some usage before they receive the intervention? These questions aren't being posed to engender confusion. Rather, you should start thinking about how much coverage is going to be a concern in your study. That being said, in a setting with over 20,000 users, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

> Another concern (but from my understanding it should be handled by the fixed effects approach) is that a user's group assignment is to some degree influenced by `BaseUsageScore`.

The individual fixed effects already adjust for users' base usage scores.

> Should I be trying to control for this disparity outside of the model above?

The individual fixed effects adjust for all *time-constant* attributes of the individual users. This allows for the selection of users into treatment on the basis of time-invariant characteristics (e.g., race, gender, height, etc.). Age is a *constant change* regressor and won't offer you much traction, especially with less than two years of data. You also won't be able to hold apart age from any other factor that is changing at a constant rate as well, a point already made quite elegantly [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149288/variable-with-constant-difference-in-time-fixed-effect-estimator). On the other hand, grouping users (e.g., age cohorts) and estimating heterogeneous treatment effects by age may be worthwhile, but outside the scope of your question.

And note that even though you're "adjusting for" stable user demographics (even those you haven't thought of), this does not absolve you from demonstrating parallel outcome paths *before* the intervention. Though average "level" differences in any one month are allowable, you still must convincingly argue that the level differences in base scores do not affect *trends* over time. Put differently, while average usage between the treatment and control group may be higher or lower in any one month, their evolution through time (i.e., month-over-month) is what really matters. The group trajectories over time should be *reasonably* similar.

Comment: Coming back to this after this project was paused! This answer has been helpful in reorienting myself. One thing that I forgot was why I was able to drop the Trt_Month*Trt_Group term. I know my control doesn't experience periods of treatment (as treatment can start at any month for the treatment group) but does it still make sense to include them in the fixed effects model or are they still contributing information?

Comment: According to your post, `Trt_Month` equals 1 for treated users *and* only during those months where the treatment is active, 0 otherwise.  The controls remain consistently equal to 0. This is, technically, your interaction term. The fixed effects obviate the need to include `Trt_Group`. Note that the fixed effects, in particular the "user" fixed effects, will adjust for all time-constant factors. A user's membership to the "treatment group" is one of those stable factors. In short, you won't be penalized for including the additional terms, though it will make the output look a bit messy.